# interruption points and clean exiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, boost-thread

See the following code:

```
boost::thread_group threads;
boost::barrier      barrier(10);
thing               pThing;

for( size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
    threads.create_thread(
        [&barrier, &pThing]()
        {
            while( true )
            {
                // do some stuff with pThing
                if( barrier.wait() )    //  let all threads catch up before resettings, and only 1 thread resets
                    pThing.Reset();
                barrier.wait();         //  let all threads wait until the reset is completed
            }
        });
}

threads.join_all();
```

### Questions:

1. Do I need a way to break the while(true) for the threads to exit correctly?
2. Will `join_all()` complete since all the threads are infinite looping?
3. what happens when a thread finishes its work, does it die?
4. Is `barrier.wait()` an [*interruption point*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points)?
5. Do *interruption points* just yield the thread?
6. What happens when the thread_group dies; Do I even need to `join_all()` if the thread group it going to die right afterwards anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you can also terminate a thread with exception.  Interruption exception is a clean way to do it.
2. Issue `interrupt_all()` call first.
3. Yes, it cannot be resumed.
4. Yes.
5. I don't understand your question.  Interruption point is a point at which 'am-I-interrupted?' flag is checked and if it's true, exception is thrown.  `interrupt()` call sets this flag on a thread and, additionally, makes the thread stop waiting if that's what it's doing currently.
6. As far as I understand, threads continue to exist, i.e. they are not somehow forced to die.  You need to make sure threads do exit (which inherently depends on what code your threads execute), then `join_all()` and only then destroy the thread group object.

Comment: Do I need to additionally call boost::this_thread::yield() or does barrier::wait() serve the same purpose?

Comment: `yield()` is actually rarely useful, and certainly not in conjunction with `wait()`.  `yield()` basically have the meaning "I have work to do, but will pause for a bit to free CPUs for other stuff", while `wait()` is more "I don't have anything to do right now, so I'll sit idle and wait (indefinitely) until something appears".